# unable to update DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

Can you please help me in updating DB2 table and is there a better way to update this huge table? Adv thxs.

```
UPDATE RT.ITEM  IM SET 
IM.ITEMNAME = GT.ITEM_D, IM.ITEMSIZE = GT.SIZE, IM.COLOR = GT.COL,
IM.ITEMINFO = GT.ITEM_I WHERE IM.RET = 14 AND IM.LAN = 10 and
  IM.ITEMK IN ( SELECT GT.SN_N FROM GD.G_TEMP GT );
```

Trying to update a table(RT.ITEM) from another schema table(GD.G_TEMP) and getting below error msg: 
[Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=GT.ITEM_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work.  DB2 doesn't support explicit `JOIN` in `UPDATE`.  But you can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE RT.ITEM IM
    SET (ITEMNAME, ITEMSIZE, COLOR, ITEMINFO) = 
         (SELECT GT.ITEM_D, GT.SIZE, GT.COL, GT.ITEM_I
          FROM GD.G_TEMP GT
          WHERE GT.SN_N = IM.ITEMK
          FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
         )
    WHERE IM.RET = 14 AND IM.LAN = 10 AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM GD.G_TEMP GT
                  WHERE GT.SN_N = IM.ITEMK
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but while executing I'm getting another error. Can you help me here. [Code: -811, SQL State: 21000]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, SQLERRMC=null.

Comment: That occurs because the subquery returns more than one row.  You can fix the error using `fetch first 1 row only`, but that might just be a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can  try with merge command, if distinct don't solve your problems in gd_temp table with multiple rows for single sn_n value then  you will have to add more filters in subquery.

```
MERGE INTO RT.ITEM IM
USING
  (SELECT DISTINCT
     GT.ITEM_D,
     GT.SIZE,
     GT.COL,
     GT.ITEM_I
   FROM GD.G_TEMP gt

  ) gt  on gt.sn_n=im.itemk AND IM.RET = 14 AND IM.LAN = 10
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET (im.ITEMNAME, im.ITEMSIZE, im.COLOR, im.ITEMINFO) = (GT.ITEM_D, GT.SIZE, GT.COL, GT.ITEM_I)
```

Comment: Thxs for your reply. While executing getting below error msg. Can you help me. Error Msg: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-134, SQLSTATE=42907, SQLERRMC=ITEM_I

Comment: Can you  please provide a ddl for these two tables  with sample data? This error  is about string   "An expression resulting in a CLOB, DBCLOB, BLOB, LONG VARCHAR, or LONG VARGRAPHIC data type is not permitted in:A SELECT DISTINCT statement,group by ...."   .   You have to add extra filter  to have  only one row per gt.sn_n

Comment: I forgot  explain why .  You have to add extra filter  to have  only one row per gt.sn_n without  using select distinct  or group by